# Ver la fecha de un conjunto de ficheros

Tags: bash, datetime

Estoy intentado hacer un script que revise la fecha de los archivos de diferentes directorios y si son mas antiguos a 7 dias desde la ultima actualizacion me envie un mail.

Para empezar, me gustaría saber cómo puedo extraer la fecha de los archivos. He probado con `ls -l | cut -f8 -d ' '` pero no me salen todas las fechas.

También me gustaría saber cómo puedo comparar dichas fechas con la fecha actual del sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procesar el contenido de `ls` es algo absolutamente desaconsejable, pues su formato no es del todo estándar. Puedes leer [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) para ver todos los detalles al respecto.

Tal y como comenta Elenasys, con `stat` puedes conseguir información sobre la última modificación, el último acceso, etc, de los ficheros.

Sin embargo, una vez obtengas ese resultado vas a tener que procesar esos datos, compararlos con la fecha actual, etc. Y eso resulta que `find` ya lo hace.

Con este comando encuentras los ficheros dentro de una estructura que fueron modificados hace más de 7 días:

```
find /dir/dir2 -mtime +7
```

De `man find`:

> **-mtime n**
>
> File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.

Si lo que quieres encontrar es solamente ficheros, añade `-type` para indicarlo:

```
find /dir/dir2 -type f -mtime +7
```

Answer (score 1):

La fecha que puedes obtener es la de "última modificación", puedes obtener un listado de archivos con stat y %y para imprimir la fecha:

```
stat -c %y "$entry"
```

para leer la fecha de ultima modificación dentro de un directorio:

```
for entry in "$directory"/* 
do
   stat -c %y "$entry" 
done
```